# Youtube landscape mode in android

Tags: android, youtube, android-intent

Am playing youtube video files by launching youtube:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(text2.getText().toString()));
                intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");

                mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way that i can `restrict user to see videos only in landscape mode`. I `dont want to show the comments and relatedvideos` etc..

Is that possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You have no control over the Youtube app... in fact, you cannot be sure the app will be installed at all.

Answer (score 4):

The solution :: :D

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID"));
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is this official? Is it written anywhere? If so, what other stuff can I use?

Answer (score 1):

No... you are basically launching the external app to display that video, once you do that you don't have control anymore.

However, if you have the video link (not the youtube link) you can try to display a media viewer and stream the video yourself:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(getIntent().getExtras() == null || !getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("uri")) {
            Log.w(TAG, "URI not found!");
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);


        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Preloading video...", "Press Back to cancel");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog1) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        final VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("uri")));
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                view.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the difference between you-tube link and Video link?? both are url's right?

Comment: They are both URLs, but one points to the Youtube page containing the video player, coments, related stuff... etc... while the other is the URL of the video itself. You can change one to another using sites such as this: http://keepvid.com/?url